# Problem finding number of elements in a list by searching for class attribute - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to capture the number of elements in a list using Beautiful Soup but I'm encountering an issue and getting a null array back. I'm pretty sure this used to work for me but not anymore.

I'd appreciate any help or pointers from the gurus out there as I'm sure there is a better way. I'm completely new to this and feel a bit lost.

So if we take a nested list like below with 3 elements:

```
<div class="row">
...
<div class="style_details">
<ul data-id="list" class="listing_details">
<li data-id="listing-index-1"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-2"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-3"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and a snippet of code to count the list elements using the attribute 'class="listing_details"'

```
browser.get(url)
c = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))  
data = soup.findAll('li',attrs={'class':'listing_details'})
links = len(data)

return links
```

Is the class being nested in an unordered list causing the issue? Any ideas how to overcome this or a better way to count items on the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only **direct** children you can use next example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div class="row">
<div class="style_details">
<ul data-id="list" class="listing_details">
<li data-id="listing-index-1"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-2"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-3"></li>
</ul>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

# print only direct <li> under <ul class="listing_details">
# note the " > " in the CSS selector
for li in soup.select("ul.listing_details > li"):
    print(li)
```

Prints:

```html
<li data-id="listing-index-1"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-2"></li>
<li data-id="listing-index-3"></li>
```

---

OR: Using `bs4` API:

```py
ul = soup.find("ul", class_="listing_details")
for li in ul.find_all("li", recursive=False):
    print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using both BS and lxml. In either case, you should be counting the number of the **children** of `<ul data-id="list" class="listing_details">`.

So with BS, it should be (using css selectors):

```
data = soup.select('ul.listing_details li')
print(len(data))
```

and with lxml:

```
data2 = dom.xpath('//ul[@class="listing_details"]//li')
print(len(data2))
```

The output should be `3` in both cases.

Comment: Thanks Jack, Yes I'm using both BS and lxml due to some limitations with BS.  I tried both lxml and BS solutions above. The lxml solution counted all children and BS didn't actually work for me.  Is there a way to limit the count to only direct children of the class as there is another list inside the lists which I don't want to count?

Comment: @DCUpro It's hard to tell in the abstract- you may need to edit your question or add a more representative sample of your html.